# Expandable for text view in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a lot of text view that under them I have 4 or 5 buttons and want now make text view Expandable to show buttons with tap on text view and hide them with again tap

i should say this buttons should send sms and send sms code are in a fragment

sorry for bad English

and item are in fragment layout

i will put a example of codes to better explane
thanks all

```
    class OrderFragment: Fragment() {

        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                                  container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?
                = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order, container, false).apply {

            // Variable and constants declaration
            val btn1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.bokhari1Reset)
            val number = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.idEdtPhone)

            btn1.setOnClickListener {

                val phoneNumber = number.text.toString()
                val message = "#9903011"
                try {
                    val smsManager: SmsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()

                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null)
                    Toast.makeText(context, "send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "please enter phone number ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } }
                bokhari1Auto.setOnClickListener {

                    val phoneNumber = number.text.toString()
                    val message = "#9903012"
                    try {
                        val smsManager: SmsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()

                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null)
                        Toast.makeText(context, "بخاری 1 = اتوماتیک کردن", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "تلفن را صحیح وارد کنید", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    } }
        }
     }
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        
        
        
        
           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bokhari2"
            android:layout_width="153dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:text="بخاری 2"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.941"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bokhari1Auto" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bokhari1On"
            android:layout_width="169dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#8BC34A"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="دستی همه روشن"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bokhari2Reset"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bokhari2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bkhari2Off"
            android:layout_width="169dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:text="دست همه خاموش "
            android:backgroundTint="#FF1100"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bokhari2Auto"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bokhari2On" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bokhari2Auto"
            android:layout_width="169dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#3F51B5"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="اتوماتیک کردن"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bokhari2Reset" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bokhari2Reset"
            android:layout_width="169dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#FF9800"
            android:text="ریست نمودن"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bokhari2" />
        
        
        
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need something like intext suffix "Read More" button. Then, you need to make custom view but if you can compromise on that, then use any of the libraries.

1. https://github.com/Chen-Sir/ExpandableTextView
2. https://github.com/Blogcat/Android-ExpandableTextView

If you got the answer you want please accept my answer by giving green check. If I haven't got your question then give me more details in comment section of this answer. Love from India.❤️

Answer (score 1):

Here is extension function to achieve expand/collapse .

```
 fun View.expand(duration: Long) {
        val initialHeight = this.measuredHeight
        val matchParentMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((this.parent as View).width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        val wrapContentMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
        this.measure(matchParentMeasureSpec, wrapContentMeasureSpec)
        val targetHeight = this.measuredHeight

        this.layoutParams.height = initialHeight
        this.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        val a: Animation = object : Animation() {
            override fun applyTransformation(interpolatedTime: Float, t: Transformation?) {
                this@expand.layoutParams.height = if (interpolatedTime == 1.0f) ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT else (initialHeight + ((targetHeight - initialHeight) * interpolatedTime)).toInt()
                this@expand.requestLayout()
            }

            override fun willChangeBounds(): Boolean {
                return true
            }
        }


        a.duration = duration
        this.startAnimation(a)
    }

    fun View.collapse(duration: Long) {
        val initialHeight = this.measuredHeight
        val a: Animation = object : Animation() {
            override fun applyTransformation(interpolatedTime: Float, t: Transformation?) {
                if (interpolatedTime == 1.0f) {
                    this@collapse.visibility = View.GONE
                } else {
                    this@collapse.layoutParams.height = initialHeight - (initialHeight * interpolatedTime).toInt()
                    this@collapse.requestLayout()
                }
            }

            override fun willChangeBounds(): Boolean {
                return true
            }
        }

        a.duration = duration
        this@collapse.startAnimation(a)
    }
```

Maintain a global variable in activity/fragment if you need some thing like Learn More/Show Less.

```
 var isCollapsed = false
    if(isCollapsed) 
       view.expand(300)
    else 
       view.collapse(300)
```

> Increase/decrease duration based on requirement.